# How to control SES reputation when allowing users to send newsletter to their customers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to make a newsletter system where users can register their own domain and send emails to their customers.

However, I noticed that SES reputation is not tied to domains, it's tied to my account.

So, how can I control my users to not sending spam or even attack my system by sending false mails which then will lower my SES reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send all bounce and complaint notices to SNS, and track your customers own bounce and complaint rates. Our system uses a special X-Header that includes the customer ID. We prevent customers with a 10% bounce rate from sending emails.

We enforce the same SES reputation requirements on our customers emails.

Comment: Ahh! I'm glad that it's possible. I was afraid that everyone will say that SES shouldn't be used for this use case.